# Calculate accuracy of fasttext classifier

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

How to calculate the accuracy of a fasttext classifier. There are in built parameters for recall and precision. But there is no function available in the source code to calculate the accuracy of fasttext classifier.

Answer (score 0):

@user054 In classification kind of problems we use a well known accuracy metric called F-measure, it is computed based on recall and precision, you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)

```
F-measure= 2 * [(precision *recall) / (precision + recall)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy = (Precision - Recall*TargetRatio +2*Precision* Recall* TargetRatio) / (Precision + Precision * TargetRatio)

where TargetRatio = (TP+FN)/(FP+TN)

Answer (score 0):

If you use single-label multi-class classification, then in fastText

> accuracy=precision=recall

Or you can use follow [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/261#issuecomment-312778400) to compute accuracy and confusion matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it this way:

```
import fasttext

def ft_predict(query : str):
    return clf.predict(query)[0][0].replace("__label__", "", 1)

clf = fasttext.load_model("model.fasttext.bin")

df.loc[:, "ft_predict"] = df["query"].apply(lambda x: ft_predict(x))
acc = [1 if x == y else 0 for x, y in zip(df["true"], df["ft"])]
print(sum(acc) / len(acc))
```